# How to upload files from the phone memory or from SD card in a Windows phone 8 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone

I have an Windows Phone app, and I need to upload file which is stored on the phone (either in the SD card or in the internal storage).

I need to build a way for the phone to browse to the file and upload to the server, which uses ASP.NET WebAPI.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @OwenPauling I know how to upload the file using Asp.net Web api but i was unable to access those files from the phone memory with in the Windows phone application